# Adding a string in between each MSSQL result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do something simple but having difficulty:

For example:

```
SELECT Val_1 + "," + Val_2 + "," + Val_3 FROM MY_TABLE
```

Result:

```
FOO,BOO,DOO
```

What is easiest way to do that?

Comment: I basically want to add a comma character in between each of the results

Comment: single quote for mssql

Comment: Your method is fine, although string constants should use single quotes not double quotes.

Comment: Im writing a script that spawns a child process via nodejs, and i was having some issues with the single and double quotes. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Val` fields are `varchar` then do below

```
SELECT Val_1 + ',' + Val_2 + ',' + Val_3 FROM MY_TABLE
```

or some sql versions on `concat` function

```
SELECT concat(Val_1,',',Val_2,',',Val_3) result FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` to do that

```
SELECT CONCAT (Val_1,',',Val_2,',',Val_3) AS Result FROM MY_TABLE
```